How to write SvelteKit middleware or interceptor for fetch both on server and client?
As title says, how to you write middleware in SvelteKit? I know to do it in hooks.server.ts.
I succeed to intercept server requests, but it would be ideal to make interceptor or middleware for both client and server calls in SvelteKit.

You could potentially handle the fetch event in a service worker (kit docs).

I tried this and it looks like it is working, but I couldn't distinguish between api calls fetch vs assets calls. All was shown as fetch. Could you help me with those?

Shouldn't that be apparent from the requested URL?

At the top of the hooks section in the SvelteKit documentation it shows the different kinds of hooks. There are client, server and both. You will have to write two separate files if you want to have normal request handlers as they are treated differently. Though there are a few things you can have that universal. Here is the section about universal hooks and here is the section for shared hooks. Those are error handling related.

I successfully written interceptor on server-side with hooks. I couldn't successfully do that in client-side hooks file. If you succeeded, could you show me working example?
